# Special character strings in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to store korean strings in my mysql database. For managing the database I am using phpmyadmin.

Whenever I try to insert a table entry containing korean letters I get the following error message:

```
 1 dataentry added.
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xEB\x8B\xAD \xEC\xB3...' for column 'name' at row 1
```

The string will then be showed as `? ?`

So my question is how to I correctly store special characters like korean letters into my database.

Comment: What is your db encoding? Best is UTF-8 or i believe UTF-16 for korean  with it there should be no problems

Comment: data field collation must be utf8_general_ci

Comment: There is no such thing as a "special character", there are only characters. What should be special about those considered "special"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two reason why some data entry miss to show their real face.

1. Don't use a meta tag in head of the page.
2. Collation not set when database create.

**Solution:**

When you insert in from a html page, you have to use a meta tag `"<meta charset="utf-8">"` in head section, so that the page can understand here is some unicode to insert.

and when you insert a unicode to your database, the field must have to `"utf8_general_ci"` Collation set.

Comment: Thanks! The collation was indeed wrong in my database